# Undefined variable: _SESSION in Laravel 5.2

Tags: session, laravel-5, controllers

```
use DB;
use URL;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{

   public function add_order(Request $req)
   {
```

I am trying to get this session variable data to insert it into database table:

```
$selected_deal = $_SESSION['selected_deal'];
```

But it gives me this error:

> "Undefined variable: _SESSION"

```
$destination = $req->input('destination');
$halal_products = $req->input('halal_products');
$allergy1 = $req->input('allergy1');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Sir, I'm using this 
  $value = $request->session()->get('key');
But still its not working

Comment: Session::put('selected_deal', '$selected_deal' );

$selected_deal = $request->session()->get('selected_deal');                                      Error: Undefined variable: request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use your Request variable:

```
$selected_deal = $req->session()->get('selected_deal');
```

Or the session() helpers:

```
$selected_deal = session('selected_deal');
```

Depend if you want to use the global request (helper) or your derived injected Request $req. In your code they should be the same.

Comment: Thanks $selected_deal = session('selected_deal'); worked